# Python - getting into a list in a very convoluted object

Tags: python, list, object, syntax

I am using pyplwnxml package to parse the polish Wordnet. The result is a wordnet object, that i am trying to load into igraph. Wordnet is a collection of relations, and synset objects (synonym sets).

After obtaining a single synset, its structure looks like in the included image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKzJY.png

And to create my graph, i need to be able to access these relations with other synsets.

How do i access, from that synset object, the list of RelationType.HYPERNYMS, and in turn, ID of these? I've tried many ways, but i just cant find any.
Looks like im having trouble with my syntax.

Comment: What have you tried? From the screenshot you posted, this should work: `a.relations[RelationType.HYPONYMS][0].id`, or for all the IDs: `[b.id for b in a.relations[RelationType.HYPONYMS]]`

Comment: Im checking it right now - it takes a while to debug because the whole wordnet takes around 5 minutes to load.

Comment: Maybe you should split off a small portion of your wordnet for testing, otherwise debugging will take ages...

Comment: NameError: name 'RelationType' is not defined - doesnt work :(

Comment: Well, `RelationType` is the name of the type, but depending on how you imported it you will have to prefix it. From quickly googling the package, `pyplwnxml.enums.RelationType` mgiht work, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Solved! Importing RelationType from pyplwnxml package helped. Thank you for your help, im new to python so the syntax is sometimes quite secretive for me. Especially when i see things like dictionary of lists of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot you posted, this should give you the ID of the shown `Synset`:

```
a.relations[RelationType.HYPONYMS][0].id
```

For a list with all the IDs, try this:

```
[b.id for b in a.relations[RelationType.HYPONYMS]]
```

Or for the IDs for all the types, try

```
[b.id for t in a.relations.values() for b in t]
```

Here, `RelationType` is the name of the enum class defining the types. Depending on how exaclty you imported the package, you might have to prefix it as `pyplwnxml.enums.RelationType` or `pyplwnxml.RelationType`.